# Performance including templates from inside for loop in Django

Tags: django, performance, django-templates

Following the Don't Repeat Yourself principle (DRY), I've refactored the Django templates I'm using.

I'm including templates from inside a for loop, and each of this included templates, in turn, can include zero or many templates.

I don't know if this will be a performance problem or Django automatically caches the templates, and once one is included using `{% include %}`, then it doesn't need to access HDD every time the same template (file) is included.

When you re-import something on Python, it isn't really re-imported again, it instead looks in the already imported modules. So, I'm wondering if Django uses a similar approach.

Comment: My tip is simply... if you need performance, use Jinja2 instead of Django as your template parser. Even though the Django template parser has improved dramatically the last few years, it's still fairly slow compared to Jinja2.

Comment: Also, in terms of DRY. With Jinja2 you can use Macros which make these type of patterns really easy and reusable. They're like Python functions within your templates which you can import.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. What I like from Jinja2 is that you can pass parameters to methods in the templates in Django you can't :(

Comment: Templates are normally fast to load in comparison to database accesses. If you are populating templates with information from the database, worry about the database first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has an optional [cached template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader) that might help.

You should however profile your app to check that template loading really is a bottleneck (I doubt it, compared to the overheads of db access etc).

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was thinking of. However, I'm using several 3rd party apps and I don't know if they're thread-safe, as required in the docs :S Is there a way to know the actual cost of templates renderization?